# Search for Nearest Neighbours in Bert Embeddings

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bert-language-model, nearest-neighbor, word-embedding

I am using the bert embeddings to generate similar words using this approach: https://gist.github.com/avidale/c6b19687d333655da483421880441950

It is working good for small dataset, but having problem with larger dataset, I am getting the error as:
memory error: numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.35 GiB for an array with shape (819827, 768) and data type float32

when handling the larger dataset having sentences more than 20000. Can anybody suggest a good way to do that and also saving the indexes and data, so it can be loaded next time easily without all the calculation!
The main code is (you can get the complete code from the above link for reference):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import numpy as np


class ContextNeighborStorage:
    def __init__(self, sentences, model):
        self.sentences = sentences
        self.model = model

    def process_sentences(self):
        result = self.model(self.sentences)

        self.sentence_ids = []
        self.token_ids = []
        self.all_tokens = []
        all_embeddings = []
        for i, (toks, embs) in enumerate(tqdm(result)):
            for j, (tok, emb) in enumerate(zip(toks, embs)):
                self.sentence_ids.append(i)
                self.token_ids.append(j)
                self.all_tokens.append(tok)
                all_embeddings.append(emb)
        all_embeddings = np.stack(all_embeddings)
        # we normalize embeddings, so that euclidian distance is equivalent to cosine distance
        self.normed_embeddings = (all_embeddings.T / (all_embeddings**2).sum(axis=1) ** 0.5).T

    def build_search_index(self):
        # this takes some time
        # I want to save this to disk, so that I can load it next time easily
        self.indexer = KDTree(self.normed_embeddings)

    def query(self, query_sent, query_word, k=10, filter_same_word=False):
        toks, embs = self.model([query_sent])[0]

        found = False
        for tok, emb in zip(toks, embs):
            if tok == query_word:
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            raise ValueError('The query word {} is not a single token in sentence {}'.format(query_word, toks))
        emb = emb / sum(emb**2)**0.5

        if filter_same_word:
            initial_k = max(k, 100)
        else:
            initial_k = k
        di, idx = self.indexer.query(emb.reshape(1, -1), k=initial_k)
        distances = []
        neighbors = []
        contexts = []
        for i, index in enumerate(idx.ravel()):
            token = self.all_tokens[index]
            if filter_same_word and (query_word in token or token in query_word):
                continue
            distances.append(di.ravel()[i])
            neighbors.append(token)
            contexts.append(self.sentences[self.sentence_ids[index]])
            if len(distances) == k:
                break
        return distances, neighbors, contexts
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a [Locally Sensitive Hashing (LSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing). I think find NNs is one important use case of LSH.